# Find neighbour LLDP - access points participating in a mesh network

Tags: snmp, access-point

Is it possible to find the neighbour in a wireless mesh network? If there is an AP say AP1 which is connected to a switch and also another AP say AP2 to form a mesh then is it possible to find the neighbour of AP1 (which is AP2) if both access points support LLDP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible however not supported by all vendors, the motorola and HP are the only access points I'm interested in. By looking at their docs I think the models that my company uses have LLDP support to discover neighbours even on a mesh link.